# Toggle conditional formatting based on cell value

Tags: google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting

I have a single calendar to keep track of important dates for several different jobs. This Google Sheet is shared with a group of freelancers who are all working on different projects. I want the freelancers to be able to toggle which events they see on the calendar by marking a single cell associated with the job they want to view with an "X".

Here is my Sheet: 
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ksnYUkIBDPhrmeTV8Q9jh15y8fldB5LadMn3DCiX_aQ/edit?usp=sharing

To the left you see I have three sample jobs (Pluth, Lopa, and Anya) Is an "X" is marked next to Pluth, I want all cells containing the word Pluth to disappear, ideally with conditional formatting.

Right now I have a conditional format that changes both the background color of a cell and it's text to white if it contains the word "PLUTH." How can I make it so that this conditional format is easily turned on and off by something within the sheet?

Comment: What would that something within the sheet be? The easiest would be a data validation with a tick and a cross (or anything else) for each freelancer's calendar to toggle.

Comment: A tick works! The more obvious the better.

Answer (score 0):

A simplified example (as Qs as supposed to provide):

[image: SO39784691 example]

where ColumnD is formatted with 'white' font and D3, D8 contain `LOPA`.

ColumnD is formatted with a formula rule for each colour as below:

Black font, green fill: `=and($A$2="x",D1="ANYA")`
Black font, orange fill: `=and($A$3="x",D1="LOPA")`
Black font, blue fill: `=and($A$4="x",D1="PLUTH")`

Adding an `x` in A3 should display the contents of D3 and D8 (`LOPA` in black font inside orange fill) and removing the `x` from say A4 should make D4 an D9 display as D3 in the image, etc.